# how to check who is listening to android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I was wondering whether it's possible to get list of all  applications listening to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but here is my take. I would be interested to know if this works.
You can check http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html
You can pass the `SMS_RECEIVED` action to this method and see if any packages are returned.